# Assume sons and daughters are born with equal probability

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

I have the following questions regarding probability theory:

In the country Malthusia, every married couple has precisely four children.

1) Assume sons and daughters are born with equal probability and independent of the other children.
Compute the expectation and variance of the number of girls in a family.

If we take $B=boy$ and $G=girl$ then we have $5$ possible outcomes (I think) if the sequence does not matter, i.e., we have $BBBB$, $BBBG$, $BBGG$, $BGGG$, $GGGG$. Each with probability $P$ $=$ $\frac{1}{2}^4$ $=$ $\frac{1}{16}$, because of the independancy. I was thinking of the following $E[G] = np = 4 * 0.5 = 2$ and $Var(G) = np(1-p) = 4*0.5*0.5 = 1$

2) Assume sons and daughters are born with equal probability and independent of the other children. A
child is selected at random from a family and is found to be a boy. Compute the expected number of his sisters and brothers.

$BBBB$ $\rightarrow$ $P$ $=$ $\frac{1}{16}$. Pick a boy gives probability $1$.

$BBBG$ $\rightarrow$ $P$ $=$ $\frac{1}{16}$. Pick a boy gives probability $0.75$.

$BBGG$ $\rightarrow$ $P$ $=$ $\frac{1}{16}$. Pick a boy gives probability $0.50$.

$BGGG$ $\rightarrow$ $P$ $=$ $\frac{1}{16}$. Pick a boy gives probability $0.25$.

$GGGG$ $\rightarrow$ $P$ $=$ $\frac{1}{16}$. Pick a boy gives probability $0$.

3) Assume that the first three children are born with equal probability and independent of the other children. However, the fourth child has the same sex as the third child with probability 1/4. A child is
selected at random from a family and is found to be a boy. Compute the expected number of his sisters
and brothers.

Any help with one of these 3 questions would be beautiful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 5 different possibilities each with probability 1/16.....hmm....but it should sum to 1. Do you know about the binomial distribution yet?

Comment: yes, I know about that distribution. That was also why I became confused because first I thought of 16 possible outcomes.

Comment: Right so you are given a random variable: $X = $ number of girls in the family. Now what is the distribution of $X$? It's binomial surely? It's actually a bit subtle the more I think about it but while X does take 5 different values 0,1,2,3,4... there are not 5 possible outcomes for the 4 children that's a slightly different thing..... so BBGG is not the same as GGBB.

Comment: This is were I troubled to find a correct answer...

Comment: Which of these have you been able to solve?  The first one is a standard binomial distribution with success probability $p=.5$ and five trials.  Standard formulas work with no problem.  The other parts are somewhat more subtle.

Comment: I tried the first one, but I am not sure if I got the correct answers. The second and third question are too hard for me at this point. I have tried to solve them for the past 4 hours.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your solution to the first part.  Note:  I should have said "four" trials, not "five".

Comment: Post edit:  your solution to the first part is entirely correct.

Comment: ok, great. But the I really do not know what to do...

Comment: For part 2:  The tricky point here is that the fact that your random sample was a boy is evidence for the claim that the family has a lot of boys.  You first need to compute the probability that a random selection finds a boy.  The answer to that is obviously $\frac 12$ by symmetry but you need to apportion that probability by the various cases.  Can you do that?

Comment: I already thought of that. But no, I cannot do that because I just simply do not know how to do it

Comment: To clarify:  the probability that the family has $0$ girls is $\frac 1{2^4}$.  The probability that you draw a boy if you sample from a $BBBB$ family is $1$.  Thus the probability that you draw a random family that happens to be $BBBB$ and then draw a random child from that family who turns out to be $B$ is $\frac 1{2^4}\times 1$.  You need to do this for $1$ girl families, $2$ girls, and $3$ girls.  $4$ girls is obvious (why?)

Comment: Ok, this clarifies it a bit. I shall try it

Comment: I edited my question as far as possible.

Comment: Good work.  And as a sanity check you should have $\sum_{i=0}^4 P(\text { i girls})\times  \frac {4-i}4=\frac 12$,  Since the probability that a randomly selected child is a boy is $\frac 12$.  Can you confirm that this holds?

Comment: no, i do not get 0.5. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should have $\{P(\text {i girls})\}=\{\frac 1{2^4},\frac 4{2^4},\frac 6{2^4},\frac 4{2^4},\frac 1{2^4}\}$, yes?

Comment: Nice, now I see it. And I can confirm that it holds.

Comment: Ok good.   So, let's call those numbers $\{p_i\}$.  Bayes now tells us that, conditioned on the fact that a random child was a $B$ , the probability that we were working with an $i$ girl family is $\left(p_i\times \frac {4-i}4\big /.5\right)=2\times p_i\times \frac {4-i}4$.  Can you see that?

Comment: yess, I see that

Comment: Then you are essentially done! Let's call those revised probabilities $\psi_i$.  Given that distribution we see that the expected number of sisters is $E=\sum_{i=0}^4 \psi_i\times i$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Part $3$ is almost identical to this $\textit {except}$ that the revised probabilities are harder to compute.  The odd condition on the third and fourth child means that, e.g.,  $BBBB$ and $GGGG$ families are a lot less likely.  It's not difficult!  Just a bit messier.

Comment: is the expectation of part 2 equal to 1.5? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $1.5$ is correct!    Note, as a crude sanity check, that we expected the number to go down since seeing the boy suggested that the number of girls was skewed to the lower numbers.

Comment: I understand that. For part 3, can you give me some more hints?

Comment: For part 2. Do I have to say E[B]=E[G] = 1.5 or do I have to state the answer in a different fashion?

Comment: Nope, that's good enough.  Trusting of course that you define your terms in your write up.

Comment: For part $3$, I'm not sure that it's worth thinking too hard about it.  You can streamline the computation considerably, but if that's not clear to you then it may not be worth the effort.   There are only $16$ possible families (where order is considered).  Just compute the probability of each separately.   Thus, say, $BBBB$ now has probability $\frac 12\times \frac 12\times \frac 12\times \frac 14=\frac 1{2^5}$, same for $GGGG$ (and same for $GBBB$ or $GBGG$ and so on.  That's how the "streamlining" works).

Comment: For BBBB I understand that the probabilty equals 1/32. Can you give me hints for the other probabilities.

Comment: The computation is exactly the same as in part $2$.  You just need to compute $\rho_i=P(\text {i girls})$ for each $i$.  I have already done $\rho_0$ and $\rho_4$ for you. You just need to compute the others.  It might help to note that $\rho_1=\rho_3$ (why?).  Note:  you could use the fact that the $\rho_i$ sum to $1$ to compute the last one (once you have done all but one) but I strongly advise against that.  Compute all of them and then use the sum as a consistency check.

Comment: I think I already see it. I did not read your hint correctly

Comment: Is it correct that E[B] = E[G] = 13/8?

Comment: I did not do it myself, but those can't be correct.  We know that the number of brothers plus the number of sisters is $3$.

Comment: Intuitively:  the odd rule should increase the expected number of sisters (and decrease the expected number of brothers).  Why?  Well, our $B$ might be the third or fourth child and if he is then we are pretty sure he has a sister, since $BG$ or $GB$ are much more likely than $BB$ for the final two kids.

Comment: Is there a way you can show me how to get the answer? This time I really don't get it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm tied up.  If you post your solution below, I will review it later.    At a guess:  if you followed the procedure from question 2 then you should have computed the expected number of sisters.  Then you could do it all again to get the expected number of brothers, but it is a lot easier to just note that the two expectations sum to $3$.  Thus, if the expected number of sisters is $\frac {13}8$, then the expected number of brothers is $3-\frac {13}8=\frac {11}8$.

Comment: For part 2, I computed E[G] = 1.5, and thus E[B] = 1.5.

Comment: If it helps you, the $\{\rho_i\}=\{\frac 1{32}, \frac 8{32},\frac {14}{32},\frac 8{32},\frac 1{32}\}$.  From there the computation follows exactly as it went in part $2$.

Comment: I already got that, so I do not know where it goes wrong

Comment: that's why I do not understand that I get E[X] = 13/8

Comment: Well, what's $X$?  If you followed the part $2$ computation, $X$ should be the expected number of sisters.  If so, great!  that answer makes complete sense.  Then, as I said, the expected number of brothers must be $\frac {11}8$.

Comment: ooh alright, because one of the 4 children is known. We need that the mean have to sum up to 3 instead of 4

Comment: Right.  We know our boy has exactly $3$ siblings.  As practice, you could of course compute the expected number of brothers the same way you did the sister.  Just to check your arithmetic.

Comment: I appreciate it you took time to help me. Thankyou, it is much clearer now

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Good luck to you.